# Typescript nullish check in another method

Tags: typescript

Its there a way to tell typescript to not complain about the use of `this.property.uid` in `doAnotherThing()` method?

I understand TS point of view, but its annoying to put `?.` or `!` or `if(this.property)` everywhere, its already "validated"

```js
export default class Alerts {
  private alertsList: AlertEntry[] = []
  private property?: Property
  
  public execSomething(){
    const prop = someMagicHere() // fetch and validate property
    if(!prop){
      return false
    }
    this.property = prop
    this.doAnotherThing()
    
  }
  
  private checkProperty(): void {
    if (!this.property) {
      throw new Error('Imóvel não definido')
    }
  }
  
  private async doAnotherThing(): any {
    this.checkProperty() // overkill, just testing and failed too

    this.property.uid // TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.    
    return {}
  }
}
```

is TS smart enough to catch this?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] where the only problems others see when they paste into a standalone IDE are the ones you're asking about.  `AlertEntry`, `Property`, `someMagicHere()` and "not all code paths return a value" and "the return type of `async` should be..." should be resolved so that nobody is distracted by them or needs to fix them to get to the starting line

Comment: (see prev comment) Once you do that: the only way to support that in TS is via an [assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), but there are caveats; one of which is that you can't narrow a `private` property that way.  If you make `property` public then [this version](https://tsplay.dev/w8YadN) might meet your needs.  If not then you'll need to refactor or assert. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer (again, after you fix your example code). If not, what am I missing?